# Define a Variable

Tags: oracle

Can I have a variable input as an alias be numerical ?

Oracle is converting it to CHAR even when I indicate NUMBER

The bottom three are fine as they are in '    '

```
DEFINE RecordMonth  = 201401 (NUMBER)
DEFINE BeginDate   = 1/01/14
DEFINE EndDate     = 1/31/14
DEFINE YearMonth   = 2014-01


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW UTIL_REPORT AS 
(SELECT
&RecordMonth as RECORD_MONTH
```

Comment: What you have shown will create a view with the `record_month` column as a number. In SQL\*Plus that works even if you actually have the `(NUMBER)` part in the define, as it's ignored. In SQL Developer the `(NUMBER)` is used in the substitution so it errors (ORA-00923). If you're seeing something else, which client and version are you using, and can you edit the question to show exactly what you do and what you see?

Comment: TOAD 11.2 gives me a char value every time I run it.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle documentations says:

---

DEFINE

DEF[INE] [variable]|[variable = text]

Specifies a user variable and assigns a CHAR value to it, or lists the value and variable type of a single variable or all variables.

---

so the "define" command save values as chars.

however you can convert it in your code to numbers by using to_number, here is an example of successfull save char(define value) in number variable :

```
set serveroutput on

DEFINE RecordMonth  = 201401


declare
 Record_Month number;
begin
  select to_number(&RecordMonth) as RecordMonth
  into Record_Month -- number variable
  from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(Record_Month);
end;
```

result is:

```
201401
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```